# Line Integral with Lemniscate

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

I am being told to integrate the function $$f(x,y) = x + y$$ over the right loop of the lemniscate $$r^2 = a^2cos(2\theta)$$

Now, we take $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = rsin(\theta)$, and as a result $dS = r d\theta$. Then, substituting we have that the answer is $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) rd\theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} r^2(\cos\theta + \sin\theta) d\theta$$
Then by substituting $r^2 = a^2\cos(2\theta)$, $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) rd\theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} a^2\cos(2\theta)(\cos\theta + \sin\theta) d\theta$$
After doing a few calculations,
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta) rd\theta = \frac{a^2\sqrt2}{3}$$.

However, the answer according to the book is $a^2\sqrt2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is unclear what you are told to do, and what $dS$ is. The quantity $r\,d\theta$ is neither a length element nor an area element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need
$$I=\int_L x+y\,dS$$
where
$$dS=\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\!\Bigl)^2+\Bigl(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\!\Bigl)^2}\,
  d\theta\ .$$
We'll try to minimise the pain in the algebra by differentiating implicitly.  Also I will minimise it for myself by asking you to do most of the work ;-)

We have
$$r^2=a^2\cos2\theta\quad\Rightarrow\quad r\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-a^2\sin2\theta$$
and so
$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta
  =-\frac{a^2}{r}(\sin2\theta\cos\theta+\cos2\theta\sin\theta)
  =-\frac{a^2}{r}\sin3\theta\ .$$
A bit more of this ultimately gives
$$dS=\frac{a^2\,d\theta}{r}\ ,$$
and now
$$\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4} (r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta)\,dS$$
is easy.