# Line integral along the "infinity symbol curve"

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I am preparing for an exam and working on the following exercise. Note that this is not homework but voluntary.

> Let $B$ be the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the equation $(x^2+y^2)^2 = 2a^2(x^2-y^2)$.
>
> 1. What is $\int_{x\in{B}}|x|^2\mathrm{d}x$?
> 2. What is the supremum of $x^3+y^3$ on $B$ (as a function of $a$)? Is this supremum reached? If yes, where?

I have found out that the curve looks like the infinity symbol and that I need to calculate the line integral along the curve. I am not sure, however, how to parameterize the curve. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Thank you very much, A.G. and Rory Daulton! Knowing that the curve is called a lemniscate, I have have found the following question: [Line Integral with Lemniscate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813259/line-integral-with-lemniscate). Putting the pieces together, I get

$$
\int_{x\in{B}}|x|^2\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x\in{B}}|x|^2\mathrm{d}S,
$$

where

$$
\mathrm{d}S = \sqrt{\Big(\!\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\!\Big)^2+\Big(\!\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\!\Big)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{2a^2\mathrm{d}\theta}{r}.
$$

Note that the definition of the lemniscate used here is slightly different from the linked question and hence the equation above also differs. Here is what I have done next:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x\in{B}}|x|^2\mathrm{d}S
&= 2\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}\Big(\!\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)^2\ \mathrm{d}S \\
&= 2\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}r^2\ \mathrm{d}S\\
&= 2\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}r^2\frac{2a^2\mathrm{d}\theta}{r} \\
&= 2\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}2a^2r\ \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= 2\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}2a^2a\sqrt{2\cos2\theta\ }\ \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= 4a^3\sqrt{2}\int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\theta=\pi/4}\sqrt{\cos{2\theta}\ }\ \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \dots
\end{align}$$

Whoops, something seems wrong. The integral does not look very nice. Any ideas?

Comment: Bernoulli knows how :) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html

Comment: What bothers me here is that the original integral is wrt $dx$, not $dS$. Are you sure you are given a line integral? Furthermore, the notation $x\in B$ is doubtful, since $x$ is just *one coordinate* of a point on $B$. Doesn't look good.

Comment: Admittedly, I am not very sure... The original exercise says: Calculate the kinetic energy of a line that follows $B$. It then states the formula given in the question. What else could that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use polar coordinates, the left-hand side becomes

$$\begin{align}
(x^2+y^2)^2
 &= (r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta)^2 \\
 &= r^4(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)^2 \\
 &= r^41^2 \\
 &= r^4
\end{align}$$

and the right-hand side becomes

$$\begin{align}
2a^2(x^2-y^2)
 &= 2a^2(r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta) \\
 &= 2a^2r^2\cos 2\theta
\end{align}$$

Equating,

$$\begin{align}
r^4 &= 2a^2r^2\cos 2\theta \\
r^2 &= 2a^2\cos 2\theta \\
r &= |a|\sqrt{2\cos 2\theta}
\end{align}$$

Note that $\cos 2\theta$ must be non-negative. Due to symmetry of both the region and the integrand, you can get your integral by doubling the integral for $-\frac{\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}4$.